# I wish to create bit comparison predicate for coredata. I am using a 32bit value as argument but it changes value when creating predicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

```
private func buildPredicateForMonths(monthFilter:Int16) -> NSPredicate? {
        // monthsFilter is never zero as every tour has a month
        let monthFilter32 : UInt32 = UInt32(monthFilter)
print("monthFilter32: \(monthFilter32)")
        let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(months & %i) != 0", [monthFilter32])
print("predicate: \(predicate.description)")
        return predicate
}
```

the output from this is:

monthFilter32: 4095
predicate: months & -2119600160 != 0

I would like the predicate to be
predicate: months & 4095 != 0

I am thinking this is a result of %i but cannot find documentation on what I need here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string passed to NSPredicate expects an integer but you are passing an array so change the predicate to

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(months & %i) != 0", monthFilter32)
```

Comment: thanks SO much - so immediately obvious when you said it but I was blind to that issue.